# What is the use-case for Sass Placeholder Selectors?

Tags: css, sass

In the Sass documentation for [Placeholder Selectors](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend#placeholder-selectors) it says

> Sometimes you want to write a style rule that’s only intended to be extended. In that case, you can use placeholder selectors ... Any selectors that include placeholders aren’t included in the CSS output, but selectors that extend them are.

It then gives this example SCSS

```
.alert:hover, %strong-alert {
    font-weight: bold;
}

%strong-alert:hover {
   color: red;
}
```

which compiles to the following CSS

```
.alert:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

The documentation seems to stop at this point which doesn't really explain what's going on here. If I just write this SCSS

```
.alert:hover {
    font-weight: bold;
}
```

it will compile to the equivalent CSS. It doesn't really explain what `%strong-alert:hover` actually does because there's no output. I understand that's the intended outcome because the quote above says "*selectors that include placeholders **aren’t included** in the CSS output*".

But that leads to the question: what is the use-case for them? Can somebody give an example of using `%strong-alert:hover`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, they are used with extend just like it is said in your copied snippet.

In your example, you could create a class that would extend it like so:

```
.error{
   @extend %strong-alert;
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

If we "unwrapped" it, this would be the same as something looking like this:

```
.error{
    font-weight: bold;
    &:hover{
        color: red;
    }
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Therefor producing this final css:

```
.error{
    font-weight: bold;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.error:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

The only major difference with using the placeholder selector is, as you stated, that the base style will not be emitted at all, it can only be used inside other declarations by using extend.

If, instead of using %strong-alert you'd have used .strong-alert, you'd end up with more CSS:

```
.strong-alert{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.strong-alert:hover{
    color: red;
}
.error{
    font-weight: bold;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.error:hover{
    color: red;
}
```

Please note that for simplicity I did not go through any "real" scss extend mechanics in the examples. The final CSS output would be a bit different:

```
.strong-alert,.error{
    font-weight: bold;
}
.strong-alert:hover,.error:hover{
    color: red;
}
.error{
    border:1px solid red;
}
```

Since extend does not create more CSS styles but rather adds selectors together. I find it a bit harder to understand the placeholder mechanic looking at it this way.

EDIT:

A possible real-world use case might go like this: I want buttons for my app and I want to be able to style them according to their meaning/context. My goal would also be to remove the need to apply numerous classes to my elements.

Where someone would maybe create a `.btn` and then a `.btn-primary`, I'd rather only have to use `.btn-primary` in my HTML.

```
.primary-bg{
    color:white;
    background-color:darkblue;
}
.alert-bg{
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
}
.btn{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid current-color;
}
.btn-primary{
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .primary-bg;
}
.btn-alert{
    @extend .btn;
    @extend .alert-bg;
}

.tooltip{
    padding:2em;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
.primary-tooltip{
    @extend .primary-bg;
    @extend .tooltip;
}
.alert-tooltip{
    @extend .alert-bg;
    @extend .tooltip;
}
```

All this SCSS would allow me to use only one class per element to be able to give it the look I want. `.btn-primary` would be enough of a class to have a fully styled button. Now the thing with this solution is that the class .btn actually exists. This would style a button correctly but without any real color on it. Because the CSS would give something like:

```
.primary-bg,.btn-primary,.primary-tooltip{
    color:white;
    background-color:darkblue;
}
.alert-bg,.btn-alert,.alert-tooltip{
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
}
.btn,.btn-primary,.btn-alert{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid current-color;
}
.tooltip,.primary-tooltip,.alert-tooltip{
    padding:2em;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

As you can see, using `@extend` simply add selectors to the extended selector, so you can use your 4 abstract classes alone, which would might not give good/wanted results. Using placeholder selectors instead would make them go away:

```
.btn-primary,.primary-tooltip{
    color:white;
    background-color:darkblue;
}
.btn-alert,.alert-tooltip{
    color:white;
    background-color:red;
}
.btn-primary,.btn-alert{
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: 1px solid current-color;
}
.primary-tooltip,.alert-tooltip{
    padding:2em;
    font-size:0.8em;
}
```

Cutting on the amount of selectors in your CSS would then reduce file size (by a couple characters only), improve performance (certainly not by much) and prevent developers from using them by mistake.

Another cool thing I can think of is if you stop using one, it will simply disappear from the produced CSS, while the non-placeholder selector would stick.

To conclude, I think that this placeholder selector option has only very niche use cases when considering the output CSS, but I do think it can provide a very useful information when reading the SCSS, which is to be able to differentiate a normal use class and an abstract one that should be extended.

Comment: That's why it doesn't seem to have any real world use-case though. Where you've written "you'd end up with more CSS", the properties for `font-weight` and `color` *are also* on `.error`. So you don't need `.strong-alert` in the first place. I'll accept this as the answer but what I'm taking away from this is they're a completely pointless feature given you can write only the necessary SCSS without using them at all (`.strong-alert` doesn't have any properties or provide anything not available on `.error`, so you could just write the SCSS for `.error` explicitly).

Comment: Ah! I get what you mean... I've never really used them myself as I prefer using composition of classes.

Comment: I've added a full example of how you'd use them, but TL;DR: I do not think this feature has any real value in itself and think we could completely do without it in 99.999% cases.

Comment: me too. I think that's why it's caused so much confusion because I just can't see why you'd use them at all. There are other ways, and none of them have any downsides over using placeholders as far as I can see. Will be interesting to see if anyone has alternative ideas but for now I think this is right.

Answer (score -1):

Placeholder selectors have the additional property that they will not show up in the generated CSS, only the selectors that extend them will be included in the output.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Because you're simultaneously describing a situation where CSS isn't emitted, followed by it being emitted. This is the reason the original question was asked. You haven't given any example or useful info - your response is as clear (i.e. completely ambiguous) as the Sass docs themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Imagine placeholder selectors as abstract classes that can be extended by other classes in the stylesheet.

```
%abstract { /* some properties */ }
.myclass
{
  @extend %abstract;
  /* more properties */
}
```

The documentation actually includes this explanation and an example to go ahead with it: [Sass: Placeholder Selectors](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/style-rules/placeholder-selectors/)

As for a much more concrete use case, placeholder selectors are useful for having classes that are extended multiple times in a stylesheet without having unnecessary code in the output CSS that might eat up precious space and bandwidth.